# Read json data from url into variables

Tags: php, json

This worked perfect for all Currencies. I can output all data with '0','1','2',...

```
$url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);

$marketname = $obj['result'][0]['MarketName'] . '';
```

And this url is for a single currency with the 'market' string.

```
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-neo
```

But how can i read this?

```
$url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries?market=btc-neo
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);

$marketname = $obj['result'][0]['MarketName'] . '';
```

doesn't work!

Any idea?

Comment: it's working for me.  Also you have missed `'` around `$url` in both your code  :- 1:- http://prntscr.com/h7xc3i  and 2:- https://prnt.sc/h7xbkg

Comment: Doesn't work is not a great hint. At least you should bother to post the precise error you got, or the value you get instead of the desired one!
The code seems ok. Are you sure that the remote read is succesfull?

Comment: this one also works:- http://prntscr.com/h7xe9c  And   https://prnt.sc/h7xemi

Comment: I think doesn't work is : all market are returned, not single one.

Comment: this url https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries?market=btc-neo don't use `market` parameter

Comment: doesn't work means.. $marketname is not filled with content!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [API](https://bittrex.com/home/api)

Use singular [`summary`](https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-neo) instead of [`summaries`](https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries) to filter on market

```
$url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-neo'
```

Comment: sorry my mistake.. i also tried with summary. but $marketname is not filled. so i think the reason ist the [0] , because with ?market=btc-neo there is only one currency. ?

Answer (score 0):

HAVE IT:

Instead:

```
$url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries?market=btc-neo';
```

This:

```
$url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-neo";
```

The key was also " instead of '

Thanks to all!